# Want to Use Application in Multiple Language Hindi and English

Tags: android

I am Using Button for Chanaging Language by clicking on the Button. I want to set the data according to the choosen Language so Please Give me the idea about swiping between to languages.

Comment: doing simple google gave me this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html and many more, have you tried?

Comment: use localization in your app

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Have a dig a google before asked?

Comment: the code below is useful for me thanks, if anything easy then it please tell me about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
       public class Languge extends Activity
   {
Button hindi ,english;
private Locale locale;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.languge);
    hindi= (Button) findViewById(R.id.hindi);
    english= (Button) findViewById(R.id.english);
    hindi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            String[] languages= Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
            Locale myLocale = new Locale("hi");
            setLocale(myLocale);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
            String[] languages= Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
            Locale myLocale = new Locale("en");
            setLocale(myLocale);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
public void setLocale(Locale value) {
    Locale.setDefault(value);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = value;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    locale = value;
}
```

}

Comment: create resource file for your language  its easy

Comment: but resourse file for eexample i made hindi resourse file just right click in resourse folder click local and put your  key in english and value in hindi

Comment: yes its helpful to me. thank you